# How to hijack the Caps Lock key for Cut, Copy, Paste keyboard operations

Tags: windows, keyboard, hotkeys, hook, capslock

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

1. To Copy, press and release <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> ONCE
2. To Paste, press and release <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> TWICE, quickly
3. To Cut, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>

The reason I want to do this is often times i find my self looking down to press the correct X/C/V key, since they're all next to each other (atleast on a QWERTY keyboard).

How can I do this on a standard keyboard (using Windows), so that it applies to the entire system and is transparent to all applications, including to Windows Explorer? If not possible with a standard keyboard, can any of the "programmable numeric keypads" do this you think?

In the above, by "transparent" I mean "the application should never know that this keystroke was translated. It only gets the regular <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> code, so it behaves without any problems".

Ps. Not sure of all the tags that are appropriate for this question, so feel free to add more tags.

SOLVED. UPDATE:
Thank you to @Jonno_FTW for introducing me to AutoHotKey.
I managed all three requirements by adding the following AHK script in the default AutoHotKey.ahk file in My Documents folder:

```
Ctrl & CapsLock::
  Send ^x
Return      
CapsLock::
If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 1000)
  Send ^v
Else
  Send ^c
Return
```

That was easy!

**NOT COMPLETELY SOLVED. UPDATE:**
The above works in Notepad, but NOT in Explorer (copying files for example) or MS Office (even text copying does not work). So, I need to dig around a bit more into AutoHotKey or other solutions. Will post a solution here when I find one. 
In the meantime, if someone can make AutoHotKey work for everything I need, please reply!

**ALL SOLVED. UPDATE:**
All I had to do was to change the capital "C"/X/Z to lowercase "c"/x/z. So Send ^C became Send ^c. It now works in ALL programs inlcuding Windows Explorer! Fixed code above to reflect this change.

Comment: @bobbymcr: I didn't know about the <kbd> tags. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the program you are looking for is [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/).

Comment: cool! My requirement (1) has been satisfied using AHK script `CapsLock::^C`. I think (3) also may be easy. I hope I can do (2)! This is a neat software!

Comment: cooler! it seems (2) is easily met as well with this script:
`CapsLock::
If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 1000)
  Send ^V
Return`
Now I just need to read the documentation more on how to write a perfect script for my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> needs.

Comment: I'm no expert on the program so I can't offer any help, sorry

Comment: @jonno_ftw, I meant that the <kbd> tags when posting the comment on StackOverflow did not work.

Answer (score 3):

You need a [Global Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx).

Comment: +1 for being correct, but please note that this method will almost certainly totally disable the caps lock key (though from the OP's examples, this is probably unavoidable, since copy is pressing the button once, ie. using it normally)

Comment: i totally want to disable the CapsLock key, so thats fine with me.

Answer (score 2):

Very nice! Been looking for something like this for a while.

My script is slightly different, making use of shift or control combinations for cut/copy, then CapsLock on its own is always paste.

```
Ctrl & CapsLock::
  Send ^x
Return

Shift & CapsLock::
  Send ^c
Return

CapsLock::
  Send ^v
Return
```

If you wanted to retain the option of retaining the Caps Lock function, I presume you could always remap e.g. Alt-CapsLock for this. I couldn't get it to toggle correctly when I tried it though.

Comment: You might like my attempt to expand on this further: http://superuser.com/questions/762273/autohotkey-organizing-hotkeys-so-as-to-use-several-hotkeys-optimally